# How do I export MySQL table to Excel with PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, excel

I am currently developing an App for my school to record Class Cleanliness Results for each class, so I need to convert the results collated in MySQL table into Microsoft Excel using PHP, preferably also able to be opened by a Android OS Phone.

I used the following PHP code:

```
<?PHP

$mysqli_user = "(user)";
$mysqli_password = "(password)";
$mysqli_host = "(host)";
$mysqli_database = "(database)";


  $filename = "grading_results_" . time() . ".xls";

  header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$filename\"");
  header("Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel");

$link = mysqli_connect($mysqli_host,$mysqli_user,$mysqli_password,$mysqli_database);
$query = 'SELECT * FROM (table_name)';

$result = mysqli_query($link, $query);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)){
 print implode("\t", $row) . "\n";
}
mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

This is how my table looks like in phpMyAdmin:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/7pr3gh06zta5d8u/Snip20150618_2.png?dl=0

This is how the Excel file looks like after I used this code to convert.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/571m9lfj64tklpc/Snip20150618_3.png?dl=0

Why is there no columns and rows? I need the Excel file to be exactly the same formatting and style as the table in phpMyAdmin. Can anyone help edit my code instead of providing me a brand new code?

Thanks in advance for your answers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Manual**

1. Run tour localhost and log in to phpMyAdmin
2. Click on your database then click on the table which you want to get
   Excel.
3. [image]

**then**

4. [image]
5. then press GO button

**With Code**

```
define ("DB_HOST", "localhost");
define ("DB_USER", "root");
define ("DB_PASS","");
define ("DB_NAME","DATABASE_NAME");

$link = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS) or die("Couldn't make connection.");
$db = mysql_select_db(DB_NAME, $link) or die("Couldn't select database");
```

then

```
$setCounter = 0;

$setExcelName = "download_excal_file";

$setSql = "YOUR SQL QUERY GOES HERE";

$setRec = mysql_query($setSql);

$setCounter = mysql_num_fields($setRec);

for ($i = 0; $i < $setCounter; $i++) {
    $setMainHeader .= mysql_field_name($setRec, $i)."\t";
}

while($rec = mysql_fetch_row($setRec))  {
  $rowLine = '';
  foreach($rec as $value)       {
    if(!isset($value) || $value == "")  {
      $value = "\t";
    }   else  {
//It escape all the special charactor, quotes from the data.
      $value = strip_tags(str_replace('"', '""', $value));
      $value = '"' . $value . '"' . "\t";
    }
    $rowLine .= $value;
  }
  $setData .= trim($rowLine)."\n";
}
  $setData = str_replace("\r", "", $setData);

if ($setData == "") {
  $setData = "no matching records found";
}

$setCounter = mysql_num_fields($setRec);



//This Header is used to make data download instead of display the data
 header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");

header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$setExcelName."_Report.xls");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Expires: 0");

//It will print all the Table row as Excel file row with selected column name as header.
echo ucwords($setMainHeader)."\n".$setData."\n";
```

[More About Code](http://www.discussdesk.com/download-mysql-data-into-excel-file-in-php.htm)

Comment: Thanks, but I need to have a PHP link to download the Excel file, without phpMyAdmin

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't work. https://www.dropbox.com/s/w4kyh9m3jqh1jdu/Snip20150619_3.png?dl=0

Comment: Hi, could you maybe provide a PDO version of this code?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT id, name, email INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/ram.csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
ESCAPED BY ‘\\’
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
FROM users WHERE id=1
```

Here `/tmp/` is address where u want to store the csv

Comment: Thanks, but I need an Excel file (.xls)

Answer (score -1):

```
  <?php
    header( "Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel" );
    header( "Content-disposition: attachment; filename=spreadsheet.xls" );

    // print your data here. note the following:
    // - cells/columns are separated by tabs ("\t")
    // - rows are separated by newlines ("\n")

    // for example:
    echo 'First Name' . "\t" . 'Last Name' . "\t" . 'Phone' . "\n";
    echo 'John' . "\t" . 'Doe' . "\t" . '555-5555' . "\n";
?>
```

// You can fetch the data from the database and display in the table. Then put the table in echo to get Excel file.

Comment: That does not return an excel file, but a CSV file with the wrong content type